# CCnet - dynamic variable

Tags: variables, cruisecontrol.net

I use URL Header Value Condition to get the date of last file changes.
But it's not static value. Because I catch new date -> force the build. After it I should use the latest date to catch the new modifications.
As I understand I should use variable for this case. But I don't understand how to set the latest date after forcing for this variable.

Comment: You say you are detecting modifications since a date, but what source control provider are you using? Git, subversion?

Comment: I use Header Value condition - http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/URL_Header_Value_Condition to check the main.js file on the server.